# MIDI keyboard latency with fluidsynth

Tags: raspbian, alsa, midi

I set up my MIDI keyboard with fluidsynth on raspbian, mostly according to this [how to](http://jacquespi.blogspot.de/2013/07/synthesizer.html).

It all works fine, but I've got a ~1 second latency. Does anybody know how to fix this issue?

RPi model: B
Raspbian image: 2014-01-07-wheezy-raspbian
MIDI Keyboard: Behringer UMA 25S

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd guess that you're gaining the delay due to some sort of buffering taking place or due to high CPU load. The later you can check by running the `top` command.

The [FluidSynth Wiki](https://github.com/FluidSynth/fluidsynth/wiki/LowLatency#low-latency-tips) suggests three command line options you can use to reduce latency.

```
-r=RATE (sample rate, default 44100)
-c=NUM  (number of audio buffers, default 16)
-z=SIZE (buffer size, default 64)
```

These go in the `start_fluid` script from that page. I'd suggest setting the last two command line options to half their default values, so 8 and 32 respectively and see if that improves performance.

Edit: if sound starts to stutter, increase them until it stops and latency is acceptable. You can change them independently as well.

Comment: I would also suggest dropping the sample rate to 22050 if you are using the on-board audio.

Comment: My latency was not one second but long enough to make playing piano really hard. I did not test the 3 settings separately, but together they make the piano keys respond 'immediately'. Problem solved

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me.
Add this lines of code to "squishboxconf.yaml" file:

audio.periods: 4

audio.period-size: 64

synth.sample:rate: 44100.000

Hope it helps!